# Unable to export textbox contents C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to export a multiple line textbox contents in a text file.

It is creating the file but not inputting any of the values. I can hard code it using double quotes and it works but when trying to use the textbox itself as the contents. Nothing is showing.

```
protected void PrintBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ingredients = IngredientsList.Text;
            string path = @"C:\Users\Donald\Desktop\Folder\ingredients.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                string createText = ingredients + Environment.NewLine;
                File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
            }

            // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
            // if it is not deleted.
            string appendText = ingredients + Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);

            // Open the file to read from.
            string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
            Console.WriteLine(readText);



        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string createText = "read from your textbox into this string";
File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
```

Simply writing to a file as above will do what you require.

Comment: but will this create a document on the desktop and allow the person to save?

Comment: Note that by default System.IO is not referenced, so it would be `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`

Comment: what is meant by path?

Comment: @DonaldBury, the path where it should be saved. You can assign that.

Comment: @ChristophKn i have updated my question. Its not adding the textbox contents to the text file

Comment: @DonaldBury, have you tried debugging it, to see if `ingredients` contain any characters?

Comment: @ChristophKn it does contain characters. What is the next steps?

Comment: @ChristophKn can you help me please

Comment: @DonaldBury, if your `ingredients` is not empty, and when your `if (!File.Exists(path))` is true, I can't see any problems.

Comment: @ChristophKn Its odd, the text file is empty but has white spacing.

Comment: @ChristophKn i debugged it, its showing theres no string in there. But there is on the page. Its just showing "" values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110649/discussion-between-christophkn-and-donald-bury).